# Get the number from which i can divide my array php

Tags: php, arrays, math

let say i have a dynamic array which have more then 2000 indexes, i want a dynamic number which i can divide that array

E.g.

```
array = 3000
dividing number =3 
chucked array = 1000,1000,1000
```

Comment: Look at [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: @George thanks for reply.. i have looked into array_chunk() and it need a number (size as mentioned in doc) .. i want that number based upon my size of my array

Comment: @awaistoor And which pattern does the number follows? (e.g. `array_count/1000 = dividing number` ?)

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what you're trying to do? It's not obvious.

Comment: basically i want to split my array into chunks ..and that array is coming from databases

Comment: This is not place to get the code for your exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it should be easier:

```
$div = 3;
$result = array_chunk($array, count($array)/$div);
```